# Dispose not being called correctly on disposable object

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have a function which draws a list of objects onto a bitmap to create a crude map. Code analysis throws a warning (CA2000) which says the object 'drawPen' isn't disposed along all exception paths. As far as I can see it is disposed at the end of the function and there is no inaccessible code where it could be missed.

Does anyone know why the compiler thinks it is not being disposed of properly?

```
public void drawUpdates(List<areaObjects> objectLocations)
{
    Rectangle areaToClone = new Rectangle(0, 0, writeOnceMap.Width, writeOnceMap.Height);
    var pixelFormat = writeOnceMap.PixelFormat;
    areaBitMap = writeOnceMap.Clone(areaToClone, pixelFormat);
    Pen drawPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
    drawPen.Width = 2;
    foreach(areaObjectsop2d in objectLocations)
    {
        int xPosition = (int)(op2d.XYZ.xPos * mapScale);
        int yPosition = (int)(op2d.XYZ.yPos * mapScale);
        Point[] crossMarker = getCrossShape(xPosition, yPosition);

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(areaBitMap))
        {
            graphics.DrawPolygon(drawPen, crossMarker);
        }
    }
    drawPen.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You aren't exception handling so technically your app could throw before the pen is disposed, use `using(var drawpen = new Pen())` or wrap your code in a try catch with a finally block that disposes the pen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the warning because in the case of an exception in your function the `drawPen` will not be disposed.

You can wrapp your code in a `try finally` and in the finally call the `.Dispose()` or better - use the `using` which does precisely that.

```
public void drawUpdates(List<areaObjects> objectLocations)
{
    Rectangle areaToClone = new Rectangle(0, 0, writeOnceMap.Width, writeOnceMap.Height);
    var pixelFormat = writeOnceMap.PixelFormat;
    areaBitMap = writeOnceMap.Clone(areaToClone, pixelFormat);
    using(Pen drawPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
    {
        foreach(areaObjectsop2d in objectLocations)
        {
            int xPosition = (int)(op2d.XYZ.xPos * mapScale);
            int yPosition = (int)(op2d.XYZ.yPos * mapScale);
            Point[] crossMarker = getCrossShape(xPosition, yPosition);

            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(areaBitMap))
            {
                graphics.DrawPolygon(drawPen, crossMarker);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
Pen drawPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
try
{
    /*Your code*/
}
finally
{
    drawPen.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I'd forgotten that using disposes of the object. Thanks

Comment: @Mike159 - `Graphics.FromImage1` for example might throw a null argument exception :)

Comment: @GiladGreen I null reference check before a series of method calls, but I will change where it is done because the current implementation isn't well encapsulated.

Was waiting to a answer time limit to expire :)

Answer (score 2):

Imagine what happens if the code between creating the pen and disposing it throws an exception. The pen will not be disposed. The compiler warns you to make sure that the pen will get disposed even when an exception occurs. You have two ways to do so: `using` and `try...finally` (which is in fact the implementation of `using`).

```
using (Pen drawPen = ...)
{
} // now the code makes sure it gets disposed
```